# Excel formula that checks the text of a specific column and the text of a specific row and returns the data listed in the table

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to display the outcome scores on one Excel sheet into another Excel sheet based on the outcome name and course.

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

If the text in Sheet1!C2=communication and Sheet1!E2=Comm 2010, then display Sheet1!D2 on Sheet2!B3.

If the text in Sheet1!C4=information* and Sheet1!E4=Commm 3000, then display Sheet1!1D4 on Sheet2!C5.

Need to be able to use Wildcard when checking the text.

If the text in Sheet1!C6=communication and Sheet1!E6=Comm2010, but there is no number in Sheet1!D6, leave Sheet2!B5 blank

I have played around with a few different IF AND formulas, but I can't get the data displayed correctly.
Right now, I am building a pivot table from the data in Sheet1, then taking the table and formatting it to match the table on Sheet1 then using `=IF(Pivot!C7="","",Pivot!C7)`. This works, but building a pivot table for each student and then formatting it to match Sheet1 is a time drain.

I'm really hoping there is a better way to do this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are compiling outcomes on a per-student basis and not in total it is safe to use the `SUMPRODUCT()` function:
[image: screenshot illustrating how SUMPRODUCT can produce the results sought]

The formula below is used in `B3`

`=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$E$2:$E$6=Sheet2!B$1)*(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6=Sheet2!$A3)*(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$6))`

and can be copied across and down throughout `B3:C4`

The formula used in `B5` is different, because of the 'wildcard criterion'

`=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$E$2:$E$6=Sheet2!B$1)*(LEFT(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6,11)="Information")*(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$6))`

(unless you are using Microsoft 365, having the formula directly suppress 0 values essentially entails doubling it in length so, as an alternative, given the small output range, a custom-number format has been implemented, which effectively doesn't display 0 in a cell where that is the formula result)